# Loop through specific index in object

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6

I have an object that looks like this

```js
const userAnswers = { 
  1: {id: 3, value: "Assistant manager"},
  2: {id: 1, value: "I am the primary decision maker"},
  3: {
    1: {id: 1, name: "Water quality management", value: "On a long list of priorities", valueId: 2},
    2: {id: 2, name: "Greenhouse gas reduction", value: "On a long list of priorities", valueId: 2},
    3: {id: 3, name: "Finanicial management", value: "On a long list of priorities", valueId: 2},
    4: {id: 4, name: "Feed management", value: "On a long list of priorities", valueId: 2}
  }
}
```

I know that I can loop through the whole object with this

```
Object.values(answers).forEach(value => { console.log(value)} )
```

But if wanted to just loop through the nested objects inside of `3:`?

EDIT: my console.log[image]

Comment: Can you add the proper object format of `userAnswers`?

Comment: You could simplify this by using arrays, there is almost no reason to use objects with numeric keys instead.

Comment: @CalvinNunes, it's an object with nested objects, that's how the senior dev wanted it...@James

Comment: @CalvinNunes I have added an image to show the object from my console.log

Comment: can you please post the object as code, not image and not copied from console.log?  There's a big difference on code and log. But anyway, if you loop through userAnswers['3'] you'll have what you asked for, you can use a simple for loop for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said in the comments, you can iterate over the values of `userAnswers['3']`, accessing it by the Bracket Notation (`object["keyName"]`)

```js
const userAnswers = { 
  1: {id: 3, value: "Assistant manager"},
  2: {id: 1, value: "I am the primary decision maker"},
  3: {
    1: {id: 1, name: "Water quality management", value: "On a long list of priorities", valueId: 2},
    2: {id: 2, name: "Greenhouse gas reduction", value: "On a long list of priorities", valueId: 2},
    3: {id: 3, name: "Finanicial management", value: "On a long list of priorities", valueId: 2},
    4: {id: 4, name: "Feed management", value: "On a long list of priorities", valueId: 2}
  }
}

var objectWithKey3 = userAnswers['3']

for (var obj of Object.values(objectWithKey3)){
  console.log(obj)
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro, btw just curious...why use ['3'] when I can use [3]?

Comment: Actually, you can, it will work. But usually when you use the number as integer without commas you are meaning/trying to access an index of an array (it's not a rule, it's just more common). Objects can be accessed by *dot notation* or by *bracket notation*. Dot notation is not allowed here because your key starts with a number.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that little caveat about dot notation, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
Object.values(Object.values(object1)[2]).forEach(item => console.log(item));
```